# Filter blur with transform animation bug in latest version of chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, transform, chromium

Running Windows 8, Chrome V. 50.0.2661.94

Prior to the latest chrome update you could apply a -webkit-filter blur with CSS and animate it with css transform while still maintaining the blur. After the update the transform animation removes the blur and it is reapplied once complete.

I've made a codepen to demonstrate it:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZzpZZ?editors=1100

The blur effect was working in last version of chrome and chromium.

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Box shadow is jacked yo!</a>

.btn {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff !important;
    transition: all .4s ease;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #236E9F 0, #145580 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #236E9F 0, #145580 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#236E9F), to(#145580));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #236E9F 0, #145580 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #1F8AD0,inset 0 -1px 4px #134a6d;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #216A9A 0, #104D75 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #216A9A 0, #104D75 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#216A9A), to(#104D75));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #216A9A 0, #104D75 100%);
    background-position: inherit;
}
.btn::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    top: 4px;
    bottom: -4px;
    background: #c2cad2;
    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(6px);
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transform: translateY(1px);
    z-index: -1;
}
.btn:hover::after {
    transform: scale(1.01, 1.1) translateY(3px);
    transition-duration: .4s;
}
```

Comment: looks fine on Chrome 50.0/Win10

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm running windows 8 w/ chrome v. 50.0.2661.94